# stopPropogration with .toggle() and jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, stoppropagation

Looking to add `stopPropogation` to the following dropdown menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('.js nav #nav-ads').toggle(
function() { 
    $('.dropdown-js').fadeIn();
    $('.js nav #nav-ads span').toggleClass('arrow-up').toggleClass('arrow-down');
},
function() { 
    $('.dropdown-js').fadeOut();
    $('.js nav #nav-ads span').toggleClass('arrow-down').toggleClass('arrow-up');
}
);
```

});

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Do you have the html?

Comment: I tried creating a fiddle but it's not toggling at all.  Basically, it's a dropdown menu and I don't want the interior click events to close the dropdown.  Focus on lines 47+ of JS.  https://jsfiddle.net/938x8fme/

Comment: formatting and noise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note:** This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed
>   in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named
>   .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the
>   animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments
>   passed. [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

---

**Modern Solution**

```
$('.js nav #nav-ads').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.dropdown-js').fadeToggle();
    $('.js nav #nav-ads span').toggleClass('arrow-up arrow-down');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: @user4413288 Yep, that'll work too. I just used the `toggleClass` shortcut for multiple classes.

Comment: Will the following method work too?  Is this method deprecated as well?  or is it ok?   `$(document).ready(function() {$('.js nav #nav-ads').click(
 function() { 
  $('.dropdown-js').fadeToggle();
  $('.js nav #nav-ads span').toggleClass('arrow-up').toggleClass('arrow-down');
 }
 ); 
});`

Comment: @user4413288 `.on` is the preferred by me, but both `.click` and `.on` will work [More info on the two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/4279440)

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure if this is outside of scope, but is there a code to get the dropdown menu to close when clicking anywhere outside the dropdown menu?

Comment: @user4413288 Maybe a `mouseover` or  css `hover` is what you are looking for. It would be more user friendly.

Comment: That fiddle is helpful.  Is there a way for it to also work in touch devices?   I.e., when user touches outside of drop down, drop down goes away

Comment: @user4413288 be sure to check/validate my answer if it was of any help.

Comment: @user4413288 - This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/jg7hcabL/1/) will open/close on touch with a fallback of hover for not touch devices.